# Django REST and React implementation model

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am currently creating a website hosted by Django. I plan to use React as my frontend framework. I have done some research on putting them together but most say that I should go for the SPA model and have separate web servers for frontend and backend. The problem is that I wish to use apache as a prod server with django and avoid having 2 separate servers. I have read about the hybrid model and having django serve static files with react.

My Biggest concern is security as I have already setup apache for security and I aware that node.js is somewhat insecure.

What would the best approach be. The separate SPA model or the hybrid model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's okay to go for hybrid model if the project is small and you are the only one working on it and you only want to make things done. I think it's kinda messy to create apps like this unless they don't really worth the time.

But if it's a big project and more than one developer is working on it or will work on it then i highly recommend going with separate web servers one serving frontend app and one django app.

Also note that you don't really need 2 different servers. You can use one server for both and use 2 different which is still not necessary and you can use one web server to serve both.

And security not something that different models can cause to downgrade or upgrade. It's up to you to configure the server and write both frontend and backend apps secure enough to do the work for you.

There are more than one web servers that are as secure as they can be and they work with both django and react pretty well. I used nginx many times to host both django and react apps and i had no problem causing by nginx itself whatsoever.

And for last piece of advice if you will; Creating good quality apps requires a lot of time and energy, working with different technologies that do really good for what they are made for and if you are planning to be a really good developer you should come out of your comfort zone and adapt with new technologies that comes out and they are coming out pretty rapidly which requires you to learn constantly and do things in way you are not used to yet and making things work even if they doesn't seem to be good together at the first look.